# Is there a form for "I have never heard of"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-requests

Some examples of what I'm trying to convey:

> - I have never heard that song before.
> - I have never heard of Miyazawa Kenji
> - I have never heard of that before?
> - I've never heard of that store?

What verb should be used? Is there a common form I can adopt?
Is there an equivalent phrase in Japanese?

Comment: Watching anime makes you familiar with lots of forms. You probably know Japanese better than me, but as an otaku, I know more Japanese sentence forms than you do :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be translated as 聞いたことがない

> 聞いたことのない歌です。 
>   宮崎賢治のことを聞いたことがありません。

Comment: Is this grammatical?

宮崎賢治は聞いたことがありません。

Comment: @StuartWoodward It may be grammatical, but sounds weird to me. It should mean "Miyasaki Keijin has not heard of (something)", but not "(I) haven't heard of Miyasaki Kenji.".

Answer (score 8):

For "I have never___" you take the verb, put it in the past tense, then add `ことがない`　or `ことがありません`.

The direct translation is something like "I don't have X experience" or "I've never done X thing"

So, for 聞く, we go:

```
聞く　--> 聞いた --> 聞いたこと --> 聞いたことがありません
```

or to answer your initial question:

```
その歌{うた}を聞いたことがありません。
```

---

For "I've never heard of that store" you can't really use this expression, you'd have to say something more like:

```
その店ぜんぜん知らない。
```

"I don't know anything about that store"

Comment: I think it would be acceptable to say you'd never heard *about* that store before: `あの店のことを聞いたことがない。`　There's two `こと` in there, but they're performing different jobs.

Comment: @Dave Yeah that works too. I don't think it sounds repetitive, the usages are so different.

Comment: What about yet? How would you say yet. As in i haven't heard the professors lecture yet?

Comment: @Myeong You would add まだ before the verb; there may be other ways, but that's the easiest :)