# 事がなければ meaning in this sentence

Tags: grammar, conditionals

> 宛名も差出人の名前もない紫の封筒があるわあるわ、ざっと目算して三百通は下るまい。
>   呪、もしくは念が宿るのかもしれない。
>   何の意味もなく、それらが有象無象の雑多な願いにすぎなくて、そして、**ここまで蒐集されてなお人目につく事がなければ、さぞ無念が生じるだろう。**
>
> According to my calculations there could not be less than 300 purple letters with no address and without the name of the sender.
>   Curses, or maybe they contain hope.
>   Without any meaning, those are people wishes and nothing more, moreover to be collected to this degree and the **fact that they might not come to bee seen, I am sure there will be many regrets.**

What does that bold sentence mean?

The fantraslation goes something like this:

> Should they ever be brought to light they would produce many regrets.

ここまで蒐集されて=Be collected up to this degree
なお=In addition to that
人目につく=Come to light
事がなければ=This situation does not happen (conditional)
さぞ=I am sure
無念=regrets
が生じるだろう=Will probably arise

Edit:
人目につく=Be visible, Be under public view.

So

> If they are not visible, it will bring regrets.

Still it is differend from the fantranslation.

Comment: See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3930/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3977/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4637/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15995/7810. By the way, I don't think "hope" is a good translation for 念. It's sort of "energy of desire/wish" strong enough to gain occult power, but I can't find an adequate word from my poor English vocabulary...

Comment: what about 事がなければ?

Comment: As you can see through the links above, `X ことがない` as a whole means "have never X", so the fantrans is almost correct, just lacks an _**n**_ before _ever_.

Comment: 人目につく=Be visible, Be under public view.

So

>If they are not visible, it will bring regrets.

Still it is differend from the fantranslation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the links given by broccoli forest? Then think of this こと as *occasion* or *chance*.

- 人目に付くことがなければ ≒ if there is no chance to be seen ...

Here's my best translation attempt:

> ここまで蒐集されてなお人目につく事がなければ、さぞ無念が生じるだろう。
>   Having been collected to this degree, yet having no chance to be seen, they (=the envelopes) are sure to hold a deep grudge.

So the author is thinking those mysterious unread letters are almost becoming like vengeful ghosts, because their innate desire as a letter has never been fulfilled.

Comment: Yeah I did read it but It still felt very weird. It's the first time I see this usage so I wanted a perfect explanation. I know I might sound gadfly but I guess this usage is still context related.
Thank you both

Comment: BTW I'm not sure if my English translation is natural, as always :-) Feel free to fix it as you like.

Comment: Wait, by reading your translation then shouldn't mine be the better one? The fantranslation is: Should they ever be brought to light they would produce many regrets. Mine is: fact that they might not come to bee seen, I am sure there will be many regrets.

Comment: @Splikie That's why broccoli forest said it lacked **n** before ever!